# How can I override these WooCommerce widget cart button functions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have already tried about 20 different methods to get this working with no solution.

I am trying to change the classes of the buttons in the WooCommerce mini cart widget as shown below.

[image]

The mark up for those buttons is written in two functions inside the wc-template-functions.php file:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart' ) ) {

        /**
         * Output the proceed to checkout button.
         *
         * @subpackage  Cart
         */
        function woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart() {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) . '" class="button wc-forward">' . esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
        }
    }

    if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout' ) ) {

        /**
         * Output the proceed to checkout button.
         *
         * @subpackage  Cart
         */
        function woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout() {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ) . '" class="button checkout wc-forward">' . esc_html__( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to override these functions within my own theme so that i can change the classes of those two buttons?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you still need help with this but this might help others in your situation.

If you want to change the class of the `<p>` tag in your example, the file you need to edit can be found in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php`

Obviously, don't directly edit the file. Copy it in to your theme (or preferably child theme) folder under `/wp-content/themes/your-theme-folder/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php` and you can edit line #75 to put in your own CSS class(es). Line #75 reads:

```
<p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons buttons"><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons' ); ?></p>
```

If you want to alter the CSS class of the `<a>` tag, then you'll need to remove the default 'action' and create your own within your theme (or preferably child themes) `functions.php` file eg.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

function my_woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart() {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) . '" class="btn btn-default">' . esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
}
function my_woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout() {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ) . '" class="btn btn-default">' . esc_html__( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'my_woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'my_woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
```

You'll need to clear your browser cache or add another item to the cart to see the changes as the cart content is saved in the browsers sessionStorage to avoid pulling a new copy on every page.

Comment: The solutions looks like it should work, but it's not working for me. I added it to the functions.php in child theme but the changes seem not to work. Is there any other cache mechanism maybe?

Comment: NVM i used a sub-theme for an sub-theme which didn't used the widget functions...

Comment: Very important point to mention that this is cached. I was stuck for an hour ^^

Answer (score 1):

The code in the old answer no longer works. **The approach is still valid** but the code doesn't work. So the following code works at the moment, you could plug it into your `functions.php`. (**April 2021**):

Shout out to Mat, thank you for your answer.

```php
function custom_widget_cart_btn_view_cart()
{
  echo '<a href="' . esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()) . '" class="button wc-forward">' . esc_html__('Custom View Cart', 'woocommerce') . '</a>';
}

function custom_widget_cart_checkout()
{
  echo '<a href="' . esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()) . '" class="button checkout wc-forward">' . esc_html__('Custom Checkout', 'woocommerce') . '</a>';
}

function custom_widget_cart_subtotal()
{
  echo '<strong>' . esc_html__('Custom Subtotal: ', 'woocommerce') . '</strong> ' . WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
}

remove_action('woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_subtotal', 10);
remove_action('woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart', 10);
remove_action('woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20);

add_action('woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total', 'custom_widget_cart_subtotal', 11);
add_action('woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'custom_widget_cart_btn_view_cart', 12);
add_action('woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'custom_widget_cart_checkout', 21);
```